# Touchpad does not work - HP isa0060/serio1/input0

Tags: drivers, usb, touchpad

The touchpad does not work directly with the CPU going on Ubuntu, but the boot the installer Win 10, abortion and restart in Ubuntu works perfectly. Even if the hibernate or sleep, still works perfectamnte. But if I turn off and turn on stops working. I pass the data.

```
dany@plata:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 090c:f37d Silicon Motion, Inc. - Taiwan (formerly Feiya Technology Corp.)
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 05e3:0745 Genesys Logic, Inc.
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB-2.0 4-Port HUB
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 03eb:8433 Atmel Corp.
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 13d3:3362 IMC Networks
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

the touchpad is ID `03eb:8433 Atmel Corp.` which also controls the touch screen.

command does not operate

```
dany@plata:~$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer id=2 [master pointer (3)]
⎜ ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer id=4 [slave pointer (2)]
⎜ ↳ Atmel Atmel maXTouch Digitizer id=10 [slave pointer (2)]
⎜ ↳ KYE Wireless Mouse id=11 [slave pointer (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard id=3 [master keyboard (2)]
↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard id=5 [slave keyboard (3)]
↳ Power Button id=6 [slave keyboard (3)]
↳ Video Bus id=7 [slave keyboard (3)]
↳ Power Button id=8 [slave keyboard (3)]
↳ Sleep Button id=9 [slave keyboard (3)]
↳ SMI id=12 [slave keyboard (3)]
↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard id=13 [slave keyboard (3)]
```

the same command when running

```
dany@plata:~$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer id=2 [master pointer (3)]
⎜ ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer id=4 [slave pointer (2)]
⎜ ↳ Atmel Atmel maXTouch Digitizer id=10 [slave pointer (2)]
⎜ ↳ ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad id=13 [slave pointer (2)]
⎜ ↳ KYE Wireless Mouse id=14 [slave pointer (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard id=3 [master keyboard (2)]
↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard id=5 [slave keyboard (3)]
↳ Power Button id=6 [slave keyboard (3)]
↳ Video Bus id=7 [slave keyboard (3)]
↳ Power Button id=8 [slave keyboard (3)]
↳ Sleep Button id=9 [slave keyboard (3)]
↳ SMI id=11 [slave keyboard (3)]
↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard id=12 [slave keyboard (3)]
```

Another command when it works, does not operate it returns nothing.

```
any@plata:~$ synclient -l
Parameter settings:
LeftEdge = 110
RightEdge = 2662
TopEdge = 78
BottomEdge = 1374
FingerLow = 1
FingerHigh = 1
```

Any solution to work forever. I can do more testing when it works and does not operate.
Now I use Ubuntu 15.10 with kernel 4.1 on the CPU.

---

I did more tests and correct data hardware problem.
The HardInfo program gave me the correct data of the TouchPad.
The rest is connected to the USB, but the touchpad is connected to the "isa"

```
Name    ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad

Type    Mouse

Bus 0x11

Vendor  Hewlett-Packard(www.hp.com)

Product 0xe

Version 0x0

Conected to isa0060/serio1/input0
```

Moreover I find the next file system

```
hp_touchpad.mpi

[Device]
Product=Touchpad
Vendor=HP
AccessProtocol=storage
DeviceMatch=usb:0830:8074;usb:0830:8072
Icon=phone-palm-pre

[Media]
OutputFormats=audio/mpeg;audio/3gpp;audio/mp4;audio/aac;audio/x-wav

[storage]
AudioFolders=Music/
```

Comment: I found the solution on Arch forum, but do not know how. https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=81331#c186 Booting with i8042.kbdreset=1 as it starts with this parameter?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Pass the link with solution:
http://www.taringa.net/post/linux/19003707/Touchpad-no-funciona---linux---Solucion.html

Finsh

Comment: Link-only answers, such as this one, are very limited in their usefulness.  If possible, could you summarize the main bits here, in case the link dies for whatever reason (so that the important bits remain kept)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but try to install

```
linux-firmware-nonfree
```

package. May be it'll help.

Comment: It did not work, another idea

Answer (score 0):

Solution in terminal:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Add `i8042.kbdreset=1` to grub

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i8042.kbdreset=1"
sudo update-grub
```